# Unable to generate Explain Plan in Couchbase

Tags: indexing, couchbase, explain

When Running the SQL against travel-simple sample data

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `travel-sample` t
WHERE (SELECT RAW t.geo.alt FROM t t1)[0] > 6000;
```

I cannot see the explain in Query Workbench.The error is

> Internal error generating query plan: Error: Parse error on line 1:\n...6000 < (correlated (select raw ((`t`.`ge\n-----------------------^\nExpecting 'IDENT', 'STR', 'DISTINCT', 'STAR', 'LPAREN', 'RPAREN', 'NOT', 'IDENT_ICASE', 'LBRACKET', 'MINUS', 'NULL', 'MISSING', 'EXISTS', 'SELF', 'COVER', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'NUM', 'INT', 'LBRACE', 'NAMED_PARAM', 'POSITIONAL_PARAM', 'NEXT_PARAM', 'CASE', 'ANY', 'SOME', 'EVERY', 'ARRAY', 'FIRST', 'OBJECT', got 'SELECT'"

What's going on?
Couchbase version:Enterprise Edition 5.5.3 build 4039

Tried Variations of the same SQl from couchbase docs:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.1/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/subqueries.html

`SELECT count(*) FROM travel-sample t WHERE (SELECT RAW t.geo.alt FROM t t1)[0] > 6000 ;`

Comment: Thanks..explain...<statement> worked.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is a bug in the Query Workbench. You can work around the bug to view the query plan by running:

explain SELECT count(*) FROM `travel-sample` t
WHERE (SELECT RAW t.geo.alt FROM t t1)[0] > 6000;

and looking to the JSON output view.

Comment: is there a JIRA ticket for this? Might be useful to link to it here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Query Workbench is not able to handle correlated keyword in 5.5.3 . This has been fixed in feature releases.

You can use REST API or cbq shell command line interface